# Bring the data to javascript and change the comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is my cshtml

[image: This is my table]

I want to call the data in the table to javascript. I want to replace the comma in the data with a period.I tried replace to controller but does not come with comma from database.I think datatable adding comma. my model name is Expense. It also I try `$("#TotalAmount").val().replace(",",".");`
or  `$("#TotalAmount").val();` js become error (Undefined)....
How should I write something?
I can't fetch the data. If I can bring it, I can make a comma dot.
Sorry for my English. :)

Comment: The comma will be added by `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)` and that's the best place to fix it.

Comment: I try but I gave an error. @freedomn-m

Comment: I think I understand what your question is and assuming TotalAmount is a decimal, you could just write @item.TotalAmount.ToString("#,0.##") instead of @Html.DisplayFor....